# Cairo Dock is uninstalled but the entry is still there in the Ubuntu login screen

Tags: 12.10, login, cairo-dock

I have tried reinstalling it and then purging the package, but the entry is still there. I have used `sudo apt-get clean` as well and I have tried using deborphan. None of these will remove the entry. Is there any other way to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the package `cairo-dock-data`

Answer (score 0):

Go into Synaptic Package Manager and search for `cairo-dock`. You'll notice that some of them are still there. Click them and mark for complete removal until they're all marked to be uninstalled. Apply.

Another method that I saw (I didn't try this because the Synaptic method worked for me) is to run this line in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins cairo-dock-data cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-plug-ins-data
```